# Is this a bug with getline(), or am I doing something wrong. Right way to use getline()?

Tags: c++, istream

It might not be a bug, but I don't know what is going wrong. 
My first entry is repeated for str1 on 2nd iteration, and is same way from then. Only first iteration goes good.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {

cout << " \n Enter two words. \n " ;
char c = 'y';
string str;
string str1;
while (c == 'y'){

    getline(cin,str);

    getline (cin,str1);

    cout << " \n\n str : " << str << " str1 : " << str1 ;
    cout << " \n Continue ? \n " ;
    cin >> c;
}

return 0;
}
```

The output is  :

```
 Enter two words.
 hello world
this is mr


 str : hello world str1 : this is mr
 Continue ?
 y
hello world


 str :  str1 : hello world
 Continue ?
 n
```

Comment: After you press `y` , you probably hit Enter. You should consider which part of the program that reads the newline made when you hit that Enter.

Comment: @chris cin is an object, maybe you mean operator>>

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thank you for providing a complete short program that demonstrates your problem. That was *very* helpful on your part. Please see http://sscce.org for more information.

Comment: @Robᵩ I have been skimming Stackoverflow, for quite sometime now, (This is my first Q). It is always helpful, and it was a tricky error I made, snippet probably saved hours of head bashing and ramming the Enter key...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
```

after your

```
cin >> c;
```

Consider the following input:

```
    dog
    cat
    y
    owl
    fish
    n
```

If we examine the characters that are present in the input stream individually, we'll see:

```
    d o g \n c a t \n y \n o w l \n f i s h \n n \n
```

The first call to `getline` consumes `dog\n`; the second consumes `cat\n`, leaving this:

```
    y \n o w l \n f i s h \n n \n
```

The first call to `cin >> c` consumes only `y` **but not the subsequent newline**, leaving this:

```
    \n o w l \n f i s h \n n \n
```

Now, the fun begins: What happens during the next call to `getline`? Why it reads up to the next newline, of course. So the next call to `getline` returns *an empty line*, and leaves `owl...` in the input stream.

The solution, as I outlined above, is to consume the remainder of the (now useless) input line.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking the same thing. You confirmed it for me. As for the solution, I am clearing the cin buffer, by using ignore(). Still it didn't work. Coz, I was putting it in the wrong position, i.e. before cin >> c. (It is a part of the project, so there is a cin >> year before I accept the choice.)

Answer (score 1):

As rob says.

But an alternative fix that looks nicer:

```
// change
char c = 'y';
....
while (c == 'y'){
....
    cin >> c;

// Into
std::string c = "y";
....
while (c == "y"){
....
    std::getline(cin, c);
```

When dealing with manual user input you should be careful of using the >> operator as this will always leave the '\n' on the input. Which means you can either use a method that retrieves the '\n' character (getline()) or you can manually remove it afterwords (ignore()).

Comment: Thanks, Look at this snippet I found the right position to ignore() the cin. :-)